# Matlab syntax, what is this function?

Tags: matlab

Given the following code snippet:

```
tscale = [7/2 7/3];
L = (tscale(2) - 1)/2;
```

What does the `tscale(2)` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tscale(2)` simply accesses the second element in `tscale`. In this case it is 7/3 or 2.3333. In Matlab it is important to note that matrices are indexed starting from 1 not 0 like many other programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

It returns 7/3. `tScale = [ 7/2 7/3 ]` creates a vector with 2 elements. `tScale(2)` returns the second element.